# Why would I not get a printed list for some ORM Methods in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

So I'm just trying to make sense of the output of the SQLAlchemy ORM methods after creating a model, committing some entries and running queries. Most queries are fine...I'm getting back a list but for some it just returns an object (see below). I know this sounds obvious but is this normal behavior? I'm specifically referring to the filter_by query as you can see below...

```
#sample_app.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 

app=Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='...'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__='persons'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Person Id: {self.id}, name: {self.name}>'

db.create_all()
```

```
#Run some basic commands in interactive mode with model already populated
    python3 
    from sample_app import db,Person

#add a bunch of persons 
    person1=Person(name='Amy')
    person2=...
    db.session.add(person1)
    db.session.commit()
    ...
```

```
#Run queries
    Person.query.all() #returns all persons as a list
    Person.query.first() #returns first item in the list 
    Person.query.filter_by(name='Amy') 
#returns <flask_sqlalchemy.Basequery object at 0xsadfjasdfsd>
```

So why am I not getting the same type of output for the third query for 'Amy'? is that normal behavior for the filter_by method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn’t execute the query in the last example. The all method brings back all object selected by the query, first is the first. You’ve specified a filter in the last example, but you didn’t execute a method which processes the query and returns a result [set].

If there are more than one Amy’s, you get all the matches with all() or the first with first(). If you had a filter which should yield a unique record, you could also use .one()

Comment: Sheesh. Thanks. I'm getting used to the syntax now, and the chaining. I just assumed the filter method could be used on its own like the all() and first() methods